# How create a file type field in custom entity programmatically?

Tags: entities, 8

This is how i create my field in my Entity content :

```
  $fields['fid'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('file')
      ->setLabel(t('Photo'))
      ->setRequired(false)
      ->setDescription(t('Product image'))
      ->setSettings(array(
          'upload_location' => 'public://produits/',
          'upload_validators' => array(
              'file_validate_extensions' => array('png jpg jpeg'),
          ),
      ))
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
          'label' => 'above',
          'type' => 'file',
          'weight' => -3,
      ))
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
          'type' => 'file',
          'settings' => array(
              'upload_location' => 'public://produits/',
              'upload_validators' => array(
                  'file_validate_extensions' => array('png jpg jpeg'),
              ),
          ),
          'weight' => -1,
      ))

      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

The field is create in my form but when i try to upload a file :

I got this error :

> Only '.txt' extension is authorized

**Edit 1 :**

In fact my settings are never read, after upload a .txt for test, the directory is wrong.

Any idea about this ?

Comment: As side note, the string you pass to `t()` needs to be in English. You don't use a call like `t('La photo de votre product')`.

Comment: True i ll change that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working example from something I'm working on:

```
'image' => BaseFieldDefinition::create('file')
      ->setLabel('Image')
      ->setSettings([
        'uri_scheme' => 'public',
        'file_directory' => 'credentialing_providers',
        'file_extensions' => 'png jpg jpeg',
      ])
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'file',
        'weight' => -3,
      ))
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
        'type' => 'file',
        'weight' => -1,
      ))
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE),
```

Comment: Nice work, wish I could give you more than 10 points for this!

Answer (score 1):

The only way i have found is to move this param into the Entityform :

```
  $form['fid'] = array(
      '#type' => 'managed_file',
      '#upload_location' => 'public://produits/',
      '#default_value' => $entity->get('fid')->value,
      '#description' => t('png jpge jpg'),
      '#upload_validators' => array(
          'file_validate_extensions' => array('png jpg jpeg'),
      )
  );
```